# how to use two tables inside a query? django

Tags: mysql, django, object, django-views, attributes

I am trying to use two tables inside one django query. But my query is resulting as "invalid JSON" format.

I want to filter data in Request table by (status="Aprv"). The Request table contains attributes 'from_id' and 'to_id'.

The uid is the id of the user who is currently logged in.

If the current user(uid) is having the 'from_id' of Requests table, the query should return data of 'to_id' from the 'RegUsers' table.

If the current user(uid) is having the 'to_id' of Requests table, the query should return data of 'from_id' from the 'RegUsers' table.

class frnds(APIView):

```
  def post(self, request):
     uid = request.data['uid']
     ob = Requests.objects.filter(status="Aprv")
     fid = ob.value('from_id')
     tid = ob.value('to_id')
     if fid == uid:
       obj = RegUsers.objects.filter(u_id=tid)
     else:
       obj = RegUsers.objects.filter(u_id=fid)
     ser = android_serialiser(obj, many=True)                       
     return Response(ser.data)
```

**I don't want to use foreign keys.**

Please Do Help me Correct the syntax.

**[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaYAI.png)**

Comment: this is a problem with serialization not with the query itself (if you paste full error it would be visible from line number) so please fix the title as it's misleading

Answer (score 0):

You may need to serialize your data to JSON using Django's serializer first:

```
serializers.serialize('json', obj)
```

note that you need to import the serializers first from django core

```
from django.core import serializers
```

To avoid using JSON serializing in every request I can recommend you to take a look on Parsers on official Django site

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

Comment: I replaced last 2 lines with this:                                                                                                                                       
obj1 = serializers.serialize('json', obj)
return JsonResponse(obj1.data)                                                                                          It did not work. Please edit on my code if this is wrong.